# How to manage Login/Logout in laravel using Auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have create one login module in laravel,what i have done yet is i have manually authenticated the user successfully and redirect on dashboard page but my issue 
is when user logged out from the application and again if they try to open that
dashboard url then it is showing error **MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection** at this time what i want is if user is not authenticated then
it will directly redirect on our login page.I have also tried to put some logic in my LoginController Constructor but it is also not working.Below is my code with file path.

**laravelproject\app\Http\routes.php**

```
Route::auth();
Route::post('/login-submit', 'LoginController@loginSubmit');
Route::get('/log-out',[
    'uses'=>'LoginController@logOut',
    ]);
```

**laravelproject\app\Http\Controllers\LoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

//to take input from user
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//end

class LoginController extends Controller
{


    public function loginSubmit(Request $request)
    {

         $email=$request->email;
         $password=$request->password;

         //var_dump($credentials);die;
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
            // Authentication passed...

             return view('dashboard');
        }
        else
        {
             return view('auth/login');
        }    
    }

    public function logOut() {


        Auth::logout();

        return view('auth/login');

    }
}
```

Error after getting logout and trying to accessing dashboard url **MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection**

Comment: where is your url for dashboard? here you are returning to view page, not redirecting to dashboard url

Comment: yes dashboard is my landing page which is definitely a view because its a html and this is  the dashboard url http://localhost/laravelproject/public/login-submit so please me to what i can change in my code to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to utilize middleware here. Create a middleware in App\Http\middleware

```
class administrator
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin() )
        {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('signin');
    }
}
```

And now in the web.php you assign this middleware to the dashboard route so that dashboard is only accessible by adminisitrator

```
Route::get('/', 'Dashboard@dashboard')->middleware(['administrator']);
```

And for Auth::user()->isAdmin() define a boolean field in users table as 'admin'
then define method isAdmin in User model like this:

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->admin;
}
```

now the process will be stream lined. whichever route you assign middleware administrator it will authenticate that route for admin. on authentication failure it will send the user to login page

Comment: Yes we can do this with middleware thank you for your help :) @Qasim

Comment: you are welcom @varun

Answer (score 0):

maintain a session for your user, and in loginsubmit() function first check if use session exist then return to dashboard view. in logout action flush the user session as

```
public function loginSubmit(Request $request)
{
     if (Session::has('user')) {
        return view('dashboard');
     }
     $email=$request->email;
     $password=$request->password;

     //var_dump($credentials);die;
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        $authData = Auth::user();
        $userData = $authData['original'];
        Session::put('user', $authData['original']);
        return view('dashboard');
    }
    else
    {
         return view('auth/login');
    }    
}

public function logOut() {


    Auth::logout();
    Session::forget('user');
    return view('auth/login');

}
```